# Can I create an instance of a class inside a method of the same class in Perl?

Tags: perl, oop

Is it reasonable to create an instance of a class inside a method of the same class?

I ask about "reasonability" and not "feasibility" because I could write a working example, like this:

```
package MyPkg;

sub new {
    ...
}

sub myMethod {
    my ($class, $param) = @_;
    my $obj = $class->new();
    ...
}
```

and the usage is:

```
use MyPkg;
my $result = MyPkg->myMethod("abc");
```

This architecture does work as expected (in `$result` I have the result of the call of `myMethod` on a "transient" object), and the caller is not even forced to explicitly instantiate a new object and then use it to call its methods.

Though, I feel this is not "Perl-ish", I mean... I don't like it. I feel something is flawed with this approach, but can't identify the exact reason.

Is there a more 'standard' solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing requires a constructor to have the name `new`, that's just convention.  Your `myMethod` sub may have a different name, but it's also a constructor.

One example of this is [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/LibXML.pod).  It has a standard constructor, but also two other constructors with specific purposes:

```
use XML::LibXML '1.70';

# Parser constructor

$parser = XML::LibXML->new();
$parser = XML::LibXML->new(option=>value, ...);
$parser = XML::LibXML->new({option=>value, ...});

# Parsing XML

$dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(
    location => $file_or_url
    # parser options ...
  );

# Parsing HTML

$dom = XML::LibXML->load_html(...);
```

The second two are probably wrappers for `new`, but they're also constructors.

Additionally, some objects are designed to be immutable.  If they allow operations to still be performed on them, they will need to return a new object of the same type.

All this is to say, yes, what you've doing is fine.

Comment: Thanks! I will study XML::LibXML code to try to understand more deeply this point...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this. It's [quite widely done](http://grep.cpan.me/?q=ref..self.-%3Enew).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about grep.cpan.me, it's quite useful...  Though I'm not really convinced that usage is exactly comparable to my use case... :-(